# Expo with Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to send push notification to specific user in Expo with Firebase Cloud Messaging but expo does not support firebase !!! please can you help me !!!

Comment: Your question doesn't show any research effort. Can you provide some code and explain what you have tried so far?

Comment: i sent the puch notification from spring boot back end and i want to get the firebase token device to recieve the notification in react native (using expo)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Expo, you need to use Expo Push Tokens to send push notifications.
You won't be able to use Firebase Cloud Messaging or any Firebase tokens.

The best way is to create a database and store all your users expo tokens.
Then, you can create a cloud function to send the notifications to theses users, using Expo servers.

Here is an example : https://github.com/nathvarun/React-Native-Firebase-Tutorials/tree/master/Project%20Files/6%20Push%20Notifications

Comment: It's in the answer : "Here is an example : https://github.com/nathvarun/React-Native-Firebase-Tutorials/tree/master/Project%20Files/6%20Push%20Notifications".

Comment: You can look at the method "registerForPushNotificationsAsync" into the file "SendPushNotification.js".

Answer (score 0):

Fierbase / messaging not working with expo managed, you can use expo barflow and link the modules and unfortunately this featcher not work in expo go or builds using expo, you have start stand alone app using ios and android approach,

So you can use expo push notifications instead and use your api to save and push notification using expo api 2, follow documents for more info.